# Chatgpt and image generation. What to see in it?

Tags: gpt

Although chatgpt is a text generative bot, it can also generate images. Yes by means of ASCII art. The results are terrible though. For example.if I ask.to generate the mona Lisa I get:

```
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣤⣤⣤⣤⣤⣶⣦⣤⣄⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
```

⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⣴⡾⠟⠛⠛⠛⠛⠛⠛⠛⠛⠻⢷⣄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣼⡏⠀⠀⢀⣀⣀⡀⠀⠀⠀⢀⡴⢻⣷⡄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣸⣿⡇⠀⠈⠻⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠟⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣿⣿⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣿⣿⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠘⣿⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢹⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠷⣄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠻⣦⣤⣤⣤⣤⣤⣤⣤⣤⣶⣦⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠻⣿⡿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⢿⣿⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠉⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Maybe I'm seeing too much into this... But it's fascinating how a text only transformer can attempt to visualise something. You can ask more and the result always varies.

You can also try to.geneneate SVG with some results.

Any explanation or idea?

Comment: I find it especially fascinating that the gpt-3.5 version of chatgpt can do ASCII art, as I thought it was trained on text only. But i am no expert and not entirely sure about this though. If it was indeed trained on text only, it is indeed counter-intuitive to me that it can draw.

Comment: Ask Google the same question and you will get some results. Those results were maybe used to train ChatGPT. Now it should be clear why ChatGPT may be able to do it. Before asking these questions, just ask on Google the same question. If you find something similar, then the trivial answer is most likely just "because it was trained with similar data". Now, I don't know which data was used to train ChatGPT, so this is just an assumption, which I think is very reasonable.